# Run AIR app without AIR runtime files

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I've made an AIR app with Flash Builder 4. Works great but I want to run the app without installing it. So..... when I install the app, I copy the files from program files and paste it on a CD and give it to somebody. He runs it on another computer without AIR runtime with as result that it doesn't work.
How can I bypass this? Like some launcher/setup that installs AIR runtime for the client if it aint installed. If it is installed, run the AIR app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Creating an AIR Badge would be a good option. 
The idea is you pass a link to the client, the AIR Badge check if
AIR is installed. If it is, installs your app, otherwise installs AIR
first.

[image: air badger]

There's a pretty good [AIR Badger tutorial on the Adobe Developer Connection site](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/airlaunchpad/). AIR Badger is an AIR App Grant Skinner wrote to make the setup easier.

Also check out the new [AIR Launchpad](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/airlaunchpad/), which is another AIR app that helps you get started with all sort of AIR related functions, including install badge.

[image: air launchpad]

Unfortunately the AIR Badger works online.

You cannot bypass AIR install. Maybe have a third party utility(batch script/etc.) that looks for air related files/.air filetype associations and based on that launches an AIR installer you supply on CD or the app itself.

On **osx** you have the **mdls** command that displays information about a file. You could check for `kMDItemKind`:

```
mdls -name kMDItemKind /path/to/yourApp.air
```

If it prints "com.adobe.air.InstallerPackage", then air should be installed, otherwise it will just print "Document".

There should be something similar for windows command prompt that checks registry file type associations. 
After you've done that check, install AIR first or just the app, depending on the result.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I looked a bit into these applications and maybe I use one of them if I can't find the perfect solution. So I prefer to try to find the perfect solution first, which you described at the end of your post.

Comment: @Lahaye Look into mdls on osx for filetype associations. Can't test on windows for now, but surely there should be something for that.