# Adobe AIR runtime

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, air, adobe, codesign

I have on `Mac OS`, an .app that is the result of an `AIR app installer`.

I want to codesign that files from it and redistribute the application like a `.dmg` file or an installer.

The question is that if you know if it is possible to make an installer or something that first checks if the `AIR runtime` is installed, and after that installs my application.
(like `.NET framework CLIENT profile`)

Comment: Salut Bodgan. One idea is to try the ***mdls* command and check if the .air application is registered with the runtime, otherwise the runtime is not installed. Check this [older answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727067/run-air-app-without-air-runtime-files/3727202#3727202) to see what I mean

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how can I know when the AIR runtime finished his installation? :-?

Comment: good question. I'm not 100% sure, but there should be an install log that gets written somewhere. The other way option would be to call mdls with a timer and check I suppose

Comment: And do you know this kind of installer, that supports these commands? Because I don't have any clue about mac os installers.

Comment: I don't know of anything outside of the box. I was assuming this would be a bash script or something which can run with or without a gui on top